# Get inputbox populated on button click in GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps

First, my coding:

```
code.gs
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar').setWidth(300);
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}
```

Above code opens up Sidebar in Google Doc.

```
index.html
<div>
<input type="button" value="Name"
  onclick="google.script.run.updateinput()" />
<input id="name">
</div>
```

This code add a button as Name which runs the next set of code and add an inputbox to sidebar

```
  function updateinput() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log("Clicked")
  app.getElementById("name").value("This is inputbox")
  }
```

Problem:

On the click of Name button the logger logs the value of Clicked, however, how can I get the inputbox to get value "This is inputbox". Please suggest.

The Execution transcript displays the following error " Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function value in object Generic."

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
app.getElementById("name").value ="This is inputbox";
```

and to get:

```
var value = app.getElementById("name").value;
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, says "Execution failed: Object does not allow properties to be added or changed."

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed to change properites. I'll look into it.

Comment: Apparantely you're not the only one having such issues. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1287

Answer (score 0):

HtmlService and UiApp are two distinct ways of creating user interfaces in Apps Script, and they cannot be intermingled. For more information on how to send data back and forth between client and server in HtmlService see the [Communicate with Server Functions guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).